# Oracle - How to use pivot key word in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, pivot

I m getting this error while I m trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle,
"ERROR line 96, col 9, ending_line 96, ending_col 13, Found 'PIVOT', Expecting: )  ..."

When I run my query out of the stored procedure template it is ok, my procedure does not take any parameters.

```
create table my_table (LOAN_NUMBER varchar2(20), DOCUMENT_TYPE varchar2(20),
                       DOCUMENT_ID varchar(20));
insert into my_table(LOAN_NUMBER,DOCUMENT_TYPE,DOCUMENT_ID) values
('992452533663','Voters ID','XPD0355636');
insert into my_table(LOAN_NUMBER,DOCUMENT_TYPE,DOCUMENT_ID) values
('992452533663','Pan card','CHXPS5522D');
insert into my_table(LOAN_NUMBER,DOCUMENT_TYPE,DOCUMENT_ID) values
('992452533663','Drivers licence','DL-0420110141769');



insert into my_table(LOAN_NUMBER,DOCUMENT_TYPE,DOCUMENT_ID) values
('692452533663','Voters ID','yPD0355636');
insert into my_table(LOAN_NUMBER,DOCUMENT_TYPE,DOCUMENT_ID) values
('692452533663','Pan card','dHXPS5522D');
insert into my_table(LOAN_NUMBER,DOCUMENT_TYPE,DOCUMENT_ID) values
('692452533663','Drivers licence','DLx-0420110141769');





CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure(pData OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN pData FOR
    select * from (
       select LOAN_NUMBER, DOCUMENT_TYPE, DOCUMENT_ID
       from my_table t
    )
    pivot 
    (
       MIN(DOCUMENT_ID)
       for DOCUMENT_TYPE in ('Voters ID','Pan card','Drivers licence')
    );
    end;
```

Can anyone please explain how to use pivot key word directly in a stored procedure?
If it is not possible, what is the logic behind that situation ?

Comment: Did you run the select standalone?  The fact that the query is in a stored proc should not matter.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't possible, or is any different from using it outside a procedure? It seems to work fine for me. Which version of Oracle are you using, since pivot isn't supported before 11g?

Comment: Yes, of course I run my query out of stored procedure and it works fine. Bu when I tried to create a stored procedure I get that error about pivot keyword. Actually I m new in oracle, maybe I m missing something simpIe m not sure. If it does not cost you much, can you please share a sql fiddle example ?

Comment: Your code compiles [as an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/859af/1). If you're running the query standalone and compiling the procedure in the same version of Oracle then the code you show will work, so something is missing from the picture. Which exact version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much! At least your sql fiddle example worked fine.  I m working on 12c. I dont know what is wrong. My query is not as simple as I shared. When I run it outside from the procedure template it works fine however I could not create the procedure. As soon as I acheive, I ll share what is wrong.

Comment: Well eventually I have found my problem, it was all about my schema. My procedure calls function from another schema, since my scheme has specific settings,  using functions from another sheme is restricted. Thanks for your help!